# store summary output of pcr object in r

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to do a Principal Component Regression using the `pls`library and I've tried to store the summary output into a variable `c` with no success. This is an example of my code

```
 library (pls)
 b <- pcr(perm ~ area + peri + shape, data = rock, validation = "CV")
 c <- summary(b)
 c
 NULL
```

What I want is to store the summary output of the pcr model into a variable so I can access to it later. 
Any hint to make this work will be deeply apreciated

Comment: What is problem with just storing `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `capture.output()` . I remember using it some time back learning it from one of the stackoverflow threads itself:

```
library (pls)
b <- pcr(perm ~ area + peri + shape, data = rock, validation = "CV")
x<-(capture.output(summary(b)))
x
```

Result:

```
> x
 [1] "Data: \tX dimension: 48 3 "                     "\tY dimension: 48 1"                           
 [3] "Fit method: svdpc"                             "Number of components     considered: 3"           
 [5] ""                                              "VALIDATION: RMSEP"                            
 [7] "Cross-validated using 10 random segments."     "       (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps"
 [9] "CV           442.5    394.7    271.2    293.9" "adjCV        442.5        393.9    269.8    290.7"
[11] ""                                              "TRAINING: % variance explained"               
[13] "      1 comps  2 comps  3 comps"               "X       94.07   100.00       100.00"              
[15] "perm    23.01    68.33    70.44"
```